# Expected number of failures preceding the first success

Tags: self-study, expected-value

I have a question that says

> What is the expected number of failures preceding the first success in an infinite series of independent trials with the constant probability of success equal to $p$?

I have tried of solution of this and is not quite sure of this:

The probability of failure is $1-p$

The probability of $x$ failures in a row is $(1-p)^x$.

Now, expectation of $x$ is

$E(x) =\sum_0^\infty x (1-p)^x\\
=(1-p) + 2(1-p)^2+3(1-p)^3 +\ldots \infty \\
=\frac{1-p}{p^2} 
$

Comment: have you ever heard of the geometric distribution?

Comment: I should check and try if it somehow corresponds to geometric distribution.

Comment: what you've described is the expected value of a geometric random variable.

Comment: In a geometric distribution to get the first success in the $x^{th}$ trial we should get $(x-1)$ failures in a row and finally a success in $x^{th}$ trial; so is the required answer something like $\sum_0^\infty x (1-p)^{x-1}p $

Answer (score 5):

The probability of $x$ failures in a row is not $(1-p)^x$. This is the probability of *at least $x$ failures in a row*. To get the probability of *exactly* $x$ failures in a row is the probability of at least $x$ failures in a row, and a success at the $x+1^{th}$ trial, *i.e.* $(1-p)^xp$.

The rest is cool. You will be able to get to the right result.

Comment: Yes since you are off by a factor of p just multiple the incorrect answer that you calculated by p.

Comment: How is it that $(1-p)^x$ is the probability of at least $x$ failure in a row? There can't be more result than $x$ results and all $x$ are already occupied by failures!

Comment: What you say is right. But to know _exactly_ how many failures in a row you get, you need a success. After $x$ failures, either you get a success, in which case you get exactly $x$ failures, or you get a failure, in which case you get at least $x+1$ failure and you have to try again until you get a success.